# Playwright /Typescript: Unable to retrieve the Cell data from table

Tags: ui-automation, playwright-test, playwright-java, playwright-typescript, javaquery

Playwright /Typescript: Unable to retrieve the  Cell data from table:

I have a table with 10 columns and nth number of rows, each cell has different locators, my expectation is retrieve full row data from the  table.
1st cell from each row has different locator and rest of the row cell has different locators.

1st cell text locator is  div and rest of the cell locators are input.  Tags of these elements are  below:

100000

In all these inputs, i am not getting any text or value to retrieve but in that locator we could see the data  and also tabindex value is also different  for each row.

Could you please help me how to handle these type of text

i tried using Textcontext(),innerhtml(), all() , HTMLinoutelement(), but no use.
when i used innerHTML() i got div elemt text but not input element

Comment: There's not enough information here to work with. Please share (1) complete, runnable code as a [mcve], (2) a package.json, (3) the site you're scraping/testing. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.